# Can $_SERVER['remote_port'] affect MySQL query success?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I'm experiencing a very strange issue with an e-commerce website: some queries, but not all, to update order's statuses are failing for some mysterious reason.

Upon a successful payment by a customer, the payment gateway calls a php-script in the online shop that should update the appropriate order's status (from 'pending' to 'confirmed').

This works in certain cases, but not others. I noticed the pattern that order_status_update() works when the callback URL is called from a particular IP (and corresponding port), but not from another.

I've gone through the code and instrumented it with a bunch of logging, and everything checked out down to the query level, but in one case it works and the other case it fails.

The only difference I can see is:

1. the IP of server calling the callback script,
2. the remote port of the server calling the callback script.

To the best of my knowledge, the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] of a call should not make a difference to anything executing (unless of course the script explicitly does something accordingly, which it doesn't), so I'm wondering if the $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] could have an effect on a MySQL/database that would cause a query to potentially fail?

When the script/query is successful, the REMOTE_PORT is 18436, when it fails the REMOTE_PORT is 49495.

I've attached the logging from the two orders, the first is successful, then second failed -- you can see they are effectively identical (except for the order_id and mdate, as expected)

When it works:

```
nab_notify - calling order_status_update with d[]=:Array\n(\n    [order_id] => 2860\n    [order_status] => C\n    [notify_customer] => Y\n)\n
ps_order::order_status_update - d[]=Array\n(\n    [order_id] => 2860\n    [order_status] => C\n    [notify_customer] => Y\n)\n
ps_order::order_status_update - curr_order_status:   order_status:C   notify_customer:1
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (1) w/fields[]=Array\n(\n    [order_status] => C\n    [mdate] => 1314093024\n)\n
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (2) order_id:[2860]
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (3) QUERY:[UPDATE `#__vm_orders` SET `order_status` = 'C',\n`mdate` = '1314093024'\nWHERE order_id='2860']
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (4) qresult:[1]
```

When it doesn't work:

```
nab_notify - calling order_status_update with d[]=:Array\n(\n    [order_id] => 2863\n    [order_status] => C\n    [notify_customer] => Y\n)\n
ps_order::order_status_update - d[]=Array\n(\n    [order_id] => 2863\n    [order_status] => C\n    [notify_customer] => Y\n)\n
ps_order::order_status_update - curr_order_status:   order_status:C   notify_customer:1
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (1) w/fields[]=Array\n(\n    [order_status] => C\n    [mdate] => 1314137858\n)\n
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (2) order_id:[2863]
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (3) QUERY:[UPDATE `#__vm_orders` SET `order_status` = 'C',\n`mdate` = '1314137858'\nWHERE order_id='2863']
ps_order::order_status_update - UPDATE vm_orders (4) qresult:[0]
```

Given the "same" query, can someone shed some light on why one would fail whereas another would succeed?

Thanks,
Eric

**UPDATE 1:**  I added query level logging and uncovered some errors, the logs reveal:

*ERROR 2006 - MySQL server has gone away*

... but strangely not for all queries within this particular session (guess that's encouraging?).  I left the line-breaks in the traces just in case they have a bearing.

I after a couple searches and other forum posts, I checked the php settings and see

```
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 60
```

which should be sufficient time?

What is strange is that this only seems to occur when a request to particular URL is done from a specific IP  (the same IP this time as when the other orders statuses were not updated).

```
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=SELECT `order_number`, `user_id`, `order_subtotal`,
                `order_total`, `order_currency`, `order_tax`, 'order_status', 
                `order_shipping_tax`, `coupon_discount`, `order_discount`
            FROM `jos_vm_orders` 
            WHERE `order_id`='2868'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT `order_number`, `user_id`, `order_subtotal`,
                `order_total`, `order_currency`, `order_tax`, 'order_status', 
                `order_shipping_tax`, `coupon_discount`, `order_discount`
            FROM `jos_vm_orders` 
            WHERE `order_id`='2868'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=SELECT user_id,order_total,order_status FROM jos_vm_orders WHERE jos_vm_orders.order_id='2868'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT user_id,order_total,order_status FROM jos_vm_orders WHERE jos_vm_orders.order_id='2868'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=UPDATE `jos_vm_orders` SET `order_status` = 'C',
`mdate` = '1314240914'
WHERE order_id='2868'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=UPDATE `jos_vm_orders` SET `order_status` = 'C',
`mdate` = '1314240914'
WHERE order_id='2868'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_vm_order_history` (`order_id`,
`order_status_code`,
`date_added`,
`customer_notified`,
`comments`) VALUES (
'2868'
,'C'
,'2011-08-25 12:25:14'
,'1'
,''
)
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_vm_order_history` (`order_id`,
`order_status_code`,
`date_added`,
`customer_notified`,
`comments`) VALUES (
'2868'
,'C'
,'2011-08-25 12:25:14'
,'1'
,''
)
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=SELECT order_item_id, event_reg_id FROM jos_vm_order_item WHERE order_id=2868
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT order_item_id, event_reg_id FROM jos_vm_order_item WHERE order_id=2868
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=SELECT id FROM jos_menu WHERE link='index.php?option=com_virtuemart' AND published=1
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT id FROM jos_menu WHERE link='index.php?option=com_virtuemart' AND published=1
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=SELECT vendor_name,contact_email FROM jos_vm_vendor WHERE vendor_id='1'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT vendor_name,contact_email FROM jos_vm_vendor WHERE vendor_id='1'
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - SQL=SELECT first_name,last_name,user_email,order_status_name,country,order_currency FROM jos_vm_order_user_info,jos_vm_orders,jos_vm_order_status WHERE jos_vm_orders.order_id = '2868' AND jos_vm_orders.user_id = jos_vm_order_user_info.user_id AND jos_vm_orders.order_id = jos_vm_order_user_info.order_id AND order_status = order_status_code
2011-08-25  02:54:48    -   JDatabaseMySQL::query - !!!! ERROR !!!! 2006 - MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT first_name,last_name,user_email,order_status_name,country,order_currency FROM jos_vm_order_user_info,jos_vm_orders,jos_vm_order_status WHERE jos_vm_orders.order_id = '2868' AND jos_vm_orders.user_id = jos_vm_order_user_info.user_id AND jos_vm_orders.order_id = jos_vm_order_user_info.order_id AND order_status = order_status_code
```

Comment: The remote port is virtually random and should not, as you say, affect anything. Can you define "doesn't work"? Is the database throwing any errors? Can you have the database log the queries? Do your SQL error logs say anything?

Comment: Looking at the error, does order_id 2863 exist in the database?

Comment: Following from @ChrisK, why are your `order_id`s strings if they only seem to be numeric? That may be the cause of the problem...? Does that query work if executed by hand?

Comment: @deceze - I've now put in some SQL logging so hopefully that will reveal something. Part of what makes this difficult is that we can't actually reproduce the error ourselves: we have to wait until customers make purchases, and then that the payment gateways calls the script from a particular server!   I've done the query by hand and it works with the order_id as a string.

Comment: @ChrisK - all signs point to 'yes'; however I'll verify this unexamined assumption...

Comment: Anyone have any ideas why Error 2006 "MySQL Server has gone away" would only happen on certain queries (but goes back to working fine on a subsequent session)?  Thanks